# Erro ao listar itens usando JSON e PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json, session

Estou inserindo itens em uma lista através de um SESSION em PHP, esses itens serão lidos em outra página usando JSON, porém está dando erro e não estou conseguindo resolver.

```
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['Cadastrar'])){
        $Nome = $_POST['Nome'];
        $Preco = $_POST['Preco'];
        $Estoque = $_POST['EstoqueInicial'];

        if(!isset($_SESSION['var'])) {
            $_SESSION['var'] = array();
        }
            array_push($_SESSION['var'], array('Nome' => $Nome, 'Preco' => $Preco, 'Estoque' => $Estoque));

    }
```

Aqui a SESSION recebe os dados do html via POST.

Em seguida criei uma session_start() para está página receber os dados da página cadastro, essa página é o que ira alimentar o JSON.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    header('Content-Type:' . "text/plain");
    if(isset($_SESSION['var'])){
        foreach($_SESSION['var'] as $_SESSION['var']){
            echo json_encode($_SESSION['var'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        }
    }else{
        echo '[{"erro": "Não foi encontrado nehum registro!"}]';
    }
?>
```

Aqui é minha requisição AJAX

```
function CarregarItens(){
    var itens = "", url = "../dados.php";

    /* Pegando os dado pelo método AJAX*/

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("h2").html("Carregando...");
        },
        error: function(){
            $("h2").html("Há algum problema na leitura dos dados!");
        },
        sucess: function(retorno) {
            if(retorno[0].erro){
                $("h2").html(retorno[0].erro);
            }else{
                /*Laço que cria as linhas da tabela*/
                for(var i = 0; i < retorno.length; i++){
                    itens += "<tr>";
                        itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].Nome + "</td>";
                       // itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].Preco + "</td>";
                        //itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].Estoque + "</td>";
                    itens += "</tr>";  
                }    
                $("#Tabela tbody").html(itens);
                $("h2").html("Carregando");
            }    
        }
    });
}
```

Em Seguida essa é minha página listar onde a magica do JSON aconteceria

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="CarregarItens()">
        <selection>
            <!--Área que mostra carregando-->
            <h2></h2>
            <!--Tabela-->
            <table id="Tabela">
                <caption>Cadastro de Produtos</caption>
                <thead>
                    <th>Nome:</th>
                    <th>Preco:</th>
                    <th>Estoque:</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </selection>
    <a href="dados.php">Listar</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Porém ele só me trás isso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Notei que no meu array ele não trás a virgula que separa os objetos penso que é isso mas não sei como colocar essa virgula ai.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se puderem me ajudar desde ja agradeço, pois isso é uma prova de um processo seletivo para um trabalho e queria muito conseguir, vlw a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro está no arquivo que apresenta o JSON.

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-Type:' . "application/json");
if(isset($_SESSION['var'])){
    echo json_encode($_SESSION['var'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}else{
    echo '[{"erro": "Não foi encontrado nehum registro!"}]';
}
```

Removendo o `for` do código faz com que os elementos sejam apresentados corretamente em um `Array`:

```
 [{
    "Nome": "Alison",
    "Preco": "120",
    "Estoque": 1
  },
  {
    "Nome": "Carlinhos",
    "Preco": "125",
    "Estoque": 1
  }]
```

O laço de repetição que você estava utilizando percorria cada um dos items da coleção `var` e apresentava cada item em formato `json`. Por isso você não via vírgulas no `json` que estava sendo gerado antes. Como o [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) interpreta o `json` de forma estrita, isso pode te gerar um erro ao executar a requisição.

Outra possibilidade de erro parece ser na função `CarregarItens`, na seguinte linha:

```
var itens = "", url = "../dados.php";
```

O caminho que está utilizando para acessar o `dados.php` parece incorreto. Remova o `../`:

```
var itens = "", url = "dados.php";
```

O arquivo `dados.php` parece estar no mesmo diretório que o `principal.php`, onde o javascript é executado. Quando você utiliza o `../` a requisição vai procurar o arquivo no diretório pai. E como o arquivo não está lá, a requisição falha.

Comment: Humm, vlw @PanterA é verdade. Um erro já foi solucionado porém a página que vai mostra o JSON ainda trás o erro que mostrei na primeira imagem, ele entra na condição error e não sucess.

Comment: @AlisonPaulo Após as alterações que indiquei o erro continua? Imaginei que esse erro fosse porque o arquivo que apresenta o `json` não estava apresentando um `json` válido, e, segundo a documentação oficial do [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), se o `dataType` for `"json"` e o jQuery não conseguir interpretar, vai ser enviado um erro.

Comment: isso fiz as alterações, porém ele entra na condição de error, não entra na sucess

Comment: @AlisonPaulo, se você abir o web inspector do chrome (geralmente pressionando a tecla `F12`) e abrir a aba `Network` e recarregar a página `principal.php` aparece algum erro?

Comment: tem sim um erro, Not Found..... http://localhost:8080/phpproject1/DesafioJunior/principal.php?_=147519995527%20404%20(Not%20Found)

Comment: @AlisonPaulo editei a resposta. Veja se te ajuda.

Comment: está no caminho certo, sim era isso eu tbm percebi que podia ser isso. So que ele não está mostrando o conteúdo no tbody, apenas aparece "carregando".

Comment: @AlisonPaulo isso é porque você está usando a propriedade de callback de sucesso com o nome errado, você está usando `sucess`, o correto é `success`.

Comment: Continuou na mesma, quase desistindo aqui =(

Comment: Deu certo agora @PanterA, vlw ai man a paciência e o esforço em ajudar !